# Unable to create certificates using cert-manager for clouddns dns01 solver

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, lets-encrypt, google-cloud-dns, cert-manager

I am trying to create certificates for my domain. I followed cert-manager docs and installed cert-manager.
I am getting the following error:

```
 cert-manager/controller/challenges "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="error instantiating google clouddns challenge solver: unable to construct clouddns provider: empty credentials; perhaps you meant to enable ambient credentials?"
```

My complete manifests are mentioned here:

https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/3168

Comment: Did you used this [doc](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/google/)?

Comment: yes Mahboob, Thanks for response. It seems issue with the version. I have upgarded to 0.16.1 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error:

> unable to construct *< provider-name >* provider empty credentials; perhaps you meant to enable ambient credentials?

Is relevant for other DNS providers as well.

If credentials are replaced by other authentication mechanism, it is recommended to specify the following flag explicitly under `extraArgs`:

```
extraArgs:
 - --issuer-ambient-credentials
```

Comment: in what section of the manifest I should input this `extraArgs`? Could you please share more context? Thanks